# Python - list of function/argument tuples

Tags: python, list, function, arguments, tuples

```
def f1(n): #accepts one argument
    pass

def f2(): #accepts no arguments
    pass

FUNCTION_LIST = [(f1,(2)), #each list entry is a tuple containing a function object and a tuple of arguments
                 (f1,(6)),
                 (f2,())]

for f, arg in FUNCTION_LIST:
    f(arg)
```

The third time round in the loop, it attempts to pass an empty tuple of arguments to a function that accepts no arguments. It gives the error `TypeError: f2() takes no arguments (1 given)`. The first two function calls work correctly - the *content* of the tuple gets passed, not the tuple itself.

Getting rid of the empty tuple of arguments in the offending list entry doesn't solve the problem:

```
FUNCTION_LIST[2] = (f2,)
for f,arg in FUNCTION_LIST:
    f(arg)
```

results in `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

I've also tried iterating over the index rather then the list elements.

```
for n in range(len(FUNCTION_LIST)):
    FUNCTION_LIST[n][0](FUNCTION_LIST[n][1])
```

This gives the same `TypeError` in the first case, and `IndexError: tuple index out of range` when the third entry of the list is `(f2,)`.

Finally, asterisk notation doesn't work either. This time it errors on the call to `f1`:

```
for f,args in FUNCTION_LIST:
    f(*args)
```

gives `TypeError: f1() argument after * must be a sequence, not int`.

I've run out of things to try. I still think the first one ought to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your comment in this code snippet shows a misconception relevant in this context:

```
FUNCTION_LIST = [(f1,(2)), #each list entry is a tuple containing a function object and a tuple of arguments
                 (f1,(6)),
                 (f2,())]
```

The expressions `(2)` and `(6)` are not tuples – they are integers.  You should use `(2,)` and `(6,)` to denote the single-element tuples you want.  After fixing this, your loop code should look thus:

```
for f, args in FUNCTION_LIST:
    f(*args)
```

See [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial for an explanation of the `*args` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Corollary question: is it possible to perform operations on the return value of the functions? Say I wanted to double the first entry: `FUNCTION_LIST = [(f1*2,(2,)), (f1,(6,)),(f2,())]` wouldn't work, would it, because you'd be trying to apply the multiplication operator to a function _object_, not the value returned by the function.

Comment: Relatedly: is it possible to call other functions in the arguments tuple, which would be evaluated when the function is called? `FUNCTION_LIST = [(f1,(time.time(),)), (f1,(6,)),(f2,())]` wouldn't give me something time-dependent, because the call to time.time() would be evaluated when the list is populated.

Comment: @poorsod: For delayed execution, you should define functions doing what you want.  For example `def double_f1(x): return 2 * f1(x)` or `def f1_time(): return f1(time.time)`.  In some cases, you can get away with `lambda` functions, but I'd recommend to use the sparingly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that such notation:

```
(6)
```

evaluates to integer value and you need tuple, so write this way:

```
(6, )
```

and your asterisk notation will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing  `*()` instead of `()`. The `*` symbol tells python to unpack the iterable that follows it, so it unpacks the empty tuple and passes nothing to the function, since the tuple was empty.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a nice alternative I have since discovered is the use of `functools.partial`. The following code does what I was trying to do:

```
from functools import partial

def f1(n): #accepts one argument
    pass

def f2(): #accepts no arguments
    pass

FUNCTION_LIST = [partial(f1,2), #each list entry is a callable with the argument pre-ordained
                 partial(f1,6),
                 partial(f2)] #the call to partial is not really necessary for the entry with no arguments.

for f in FUNCTION_LIST: f()
```